# App Factory 2.1.0 error when starting

Tags: wso2

I'm trying to start AppFactory 2.1.0 but can't find out how to achieve it. This is the error log it gives me every time I try to run it.

Hope you can help me, Regards.

```
[2015-06-29 17:22:13,242]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.bootup.validator.util.ValidationResultPrinter} -  The default keystore (wso2carbon.jks) is currently being used. To maximize security when deploying to a production environment, configure a new keystore with a unique password in the production server profile.
[2015-06-29 17:22:13,413]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.AgentHolder} -  Agent created !
[2015-06-29 17:22:13,470]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.internal.AgentDS} -  Successfully deployed Agent Client
[2015-06-29 17:22:13,878]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.ldap.server.configuration.LDAPConfigurationBuilder} -  KDC server is disabled.
[2015-06-29 17:22:14,210]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.ldap.server.DirectoryActivator} -  Initializing Directory Server with working directory /home/omarete/Documentos/wso2appfactory-2.1.0/repository/data/org.wso2.carbon.directory and port 10389
[2015-06-29 17:22:20,843]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.social.core.internal.SocialComponent} -  Social Activity bundle is activated
[2015-06-29 17:22:21,229] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.AsyncDataPublisher} -  Error while connection to event receiver
org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.exception.AgentException: Cannot borrow client for TCP,bam.AF_HOST:7614,TCP,bam.AF_HOST:7714
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.internal.publisher.authenticator.AgentAuthenticator.connect(AgentAuthenticator.java:58)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.DataPublisher.start(DataPublisher.java:273)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.DataPublisher.<init>(DataPublisher.java:161)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.AsyncDataPublisher$ReceiverConnectionWorker.run(AsyncDataPublisher.java:843)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Could not connect to bam.AF_HOST on port 7714
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.createClient(TSSLTransportFactory.java:212)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.getClientSocket(TSSLTransportFactory.java:166)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.internal.pool.client.secure.SecureClientPoolFactory.makeObject(SecureClientPoolFactory.java:90)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.internal.pool.client.secure.SecureClientPoolFactory.makeObject(SecureClientPoolFactory.java:48)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1212)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.internal.publisher.authenticator.AgentAuthenticator.connect(AgentAuthenticator.java:50)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: bam.AF_HOST
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:178)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:618)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(SSLSocketImpl.java:407)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(SSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:88)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.createClient(TSSLTransportFactory.java:208)
    ... 13 more
[2015-06-29 17:22:25,598] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm} -  Cannot create org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:329)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.initializeObjects(DefaultRealm.java:195)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:104)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:223)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:101)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:114)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:69)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Admin user has not been created. Error occurs while creating Admin user in primary user store.
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.addInitialAdminData(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:3221)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.<init>(ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.java:166)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.<init>(ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.java:102)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: User name not valid. User name must be a non null string with following format, [a-zA-Z0-9._-|//]{3,30}$
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.doAddUserValidityChecks(ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.java:295)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.doAddUser(ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.java:236)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.addInitialAdminData(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:3215)
    ... 29 more
[2015-06-29 17:22:25,605] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService} -  Cannot initialize the realm.
org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:370)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.initializeObjects(DefaultRealm.java:195)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:104)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:223)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:101)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:114)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:69)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:329)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Admin user has not been created. Error occurs while creating Admin user in primary user store.
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.addInitialAdminData(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:3221)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.<init>(ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.java:166)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.<init>(ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.java:102)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: User name not valid. User name must be a non null string with following format, [a-zA-Z0-9._-|//]{3,30}$
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.doAddUserValidityChecks(ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.java:295)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.doAddUser(ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.java:236)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.addInitialAdminData(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:3215)
    ... 29 more
[2015-06-29 17:22:25,608] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator} -  Cannot start User Manager Core bundle
org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Cannot initialize the realm.
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:231)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:101)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:114)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:69)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:370)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.initializeObjects(DefaultRealm.java:195)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:104)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:223)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:329)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Admin user has not been created. Error occurs while creating Admin user in primary user store.
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.addInitialAdminData(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:3221)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.<init>(ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.java:166)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.<init>(ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.java:102)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: User name not valid. User name must be a non null string with following format, [a-zA-Z0-9._-|//]{3,30}$
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.doAddUserValidityChecks(ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.java:295)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.doAddUser(ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.java:236)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.addInitialAdminData(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:3215)
    ... 29 more
[2015-06-29 17:22:49,910] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.lb.ReceiverGroup} -  No receiver is reachable at reconnection, can't publish the events
[2015-06-29 17:22:49,919] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.AsyncDataPublisher} -  Reconnection failed for for tcp://bam.AF_HOST:7614
[2015-06-29 17:23:19,910] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.lb.ReceiverGroup} -  No receiver is reachable at reconnection, can't publish the events
[2015-06-29 17:23:19,920] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.AsyncDataPublisher} -  Reconnection failed for for tcp://bam.AF_HOST:7614
```

PS: I'm based on this tutorials of WSO2: http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/2015/02/tutorial-step-by-step-guide-on-installing-and-configuring-wso2-app-factory-puppet-master-using-virtu/

https://docs.wso2.com/display/AF210/Configuring+the+Environment

Comment: It looks like the Thrift publisher is not able to connect to the Thrift receiver on BAM. And from `Could not connect to bam.AF_HOST on port 7714` it seems that AF_HOST has to be configured somewhere, and has been not.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, it seems to me that the package provided by wso2 requires a lot more of configuration than appears to be. can you provide me with a tutorial or link that could give me a lead to setup the appfactory?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

From [1] it seems that if you configure the AppFactory domain correctly in the Puppet master, it should replace the string AF_HOST in the relevant places. If you have correctly configured this but it still is not working, try mappping bam.AF_HOST to your BAM server IP in `/etc/hosts`.

I couldn't find a detailed tutorial later than the one you're following though. You can always seek help from WSO2 developer mailing list [2].

[1] - https://github.com/wso2/product-af/blob/wso2appfactory-2.1.0/modules/puppet-manifests/appfactory/manifests/nodes.pp#L89

[2] - http://wso2.com/mail/